# Endomorphisms of $\mathbb C^{\times}$

Tags: group-theory

What are all continuous multiplicative endomorphisms of $\mathbb C$?

As $\mathbb C^{\times} \simeq \mathbb R_{>0}^{\times}\times S^1$ this question can be reduced to the description of continuous homomorphisms (i) $\mathbb R_{>0}^{\times} \to \mathbb R_{>0}^{\times}$, (ii) $\mathbb R_{>0}^{\times} \to S^1$, (iii) $S^1\to \mathbb R_{>0}^{\times}$, (iv) $S^1\to S^1$. I've got the answers in all the cases but (ii): (i) - exponentiation to real powers, (iii) - only trivial endomorphism, (iv) - exponentiation to integer powers. I look forward to any help with the case (ii).

Comment: As a topological group, $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}^\times$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},+)$. Does that give you an idea?